# How to deploy a shared library?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I would like to "quickly" deploy a shared library on my Ubuntu. It is for a short term project so I don't want to use auto-tools here, but do everything manually.

So I built my library with this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -fPIC -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)

lib%.so: %.o | dist
    $(CC) -shared -o dist/$@ $^

dist:
    mkdir -p dist

install: lib
    mkdir -p $(PREFIX)/lib/foobar
    mkdir -p $(PREFIX)/include/foobar
    cp dist/*.so $(PREFIX)/lib/foobar
    cp dist/*.h $(PREFIX)/include/foobar
    ldconfig $(PREFIX)/lib/foobar/
```

In another project, I would like to use `libfoo.so` now located in `/usr/lib/foobar/libfoo.so`. So I've built it with:

```
$(CC) test.c -lfoo
```

Unfortunately I have this issue:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
```

I now that I can do `-L/usr/lib/foobar/libfoo.so` but this location should be known by my operating system.

Am I forced to put it directly into `/usr/lib`? I have the same issue with `/usr/local/lib` which doesn't seem to be the default route to be used with `gcc ... -l...`

How should I normally deploy a shared library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of directories from `ld.so.conf` has system-wide impact; the runtime linker will search those dirs when starting *any* dynamic binary.  Unless you actually want additional system-wide overhead, it's more efficient to *privately* search another dir on a custom / as-needed basis.  Private-search is ideally suited for cases of 1-off or single-use or rarely-used custom libs.

For the 1 or few bins that reference those libs, bins can be rebuilt with a directive for the runtime linker to *privately* search 1+ custom dirs; eg:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64 -lblah
```

For more details, see `gcc` and `ld` manual pages for the respective options `-Wl,` and `-rpath`.

Answer (score 1):

To make a directory known to the dynamic linker (`ld.so`) so that it can be found at **run-time** without depending on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

- list it in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or in an include file under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, if the main `/etc/ld.so.conf` file has an appropriate `include` statement to enable this)
- then run `/sbin/ldconfig`

As regards the **build-time** linker (`ld`), it is normal to expect to have to specify the library location explicitly using the `-L` flag on the compiler, normally with the directory as argument e.g. `-L/usr/lib/foobar`.  However, according to the manual page for the compile-time linker, `ld`, the search path for libraries does contain (after everything else) the directories referenced by `/etc/ld.so.conf`.  So although `ld.so.conf` is primarily intended for use with the run-time linker as the name suggests, the build-time linker will in fact find your library once you have listed the directory there.