# Releasing a binary application with opencv c++

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, deb

I have a c++ application that I would like to release as deb package.  The issue I am running into is differing versions of OpenCV across different computers.  When running the program on a different machine than it was compiled on, it gives `error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.405: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I then ran ldd and it returned

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc1a7a3000)
libopencv_highgui.so.405 => not found
libopencv_videoio.so.405 => not found
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.405 => not found
libopencv_imgproc.so.405 => not found
libopencv_core.so.405 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f650380a000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f65037ef000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f65037cc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f65035da000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f650348b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6503a3e000)
```

On that machine, I have libopencv_core.so.4.2.  Is there a way to either package opencv with the app, or make it use the generic libopencv_core.so, which is a symlink to the installed version?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62022936/2393191 you can tell during linking where the runtime linker should search for the shared lib. So you would deploy the lib together with your binary application and don't install that library system-wide. But I don't know more about that,pnly read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> When running the program on a different machine than it was compiled on, it gives `error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.405: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

For solving this problem I cannot recommend enough [Exodus](https://github.com/intoli/exodus):

> **Painless relocation of Linux binaries and all of their dependencies without containers.**
>
> Exodus is a tool that makes it easy to successfully relocate Linux ELF binaries from one system to another. This is useful in situations where you don't have root access on a machine or where a package simply isn't available for a given Linux distribution.